# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException Error creating bean with name 'certificateOrderRepository'

Tags: java, spring

Hello i'm a newbee in spring framework and i am trying to do testing using jUnit. Whenever i run my test, i keep on having this error. can anyone please help me.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'certificateOrderRepository': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'systemConfigurationDto' defined in file [E:\confidential\Global_Sign\40_Make\royaljelly-pc\target\test-classes\test-applicationContext-bean.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'mtaDto.password' of bean class [com.globalsign.hb.dto.SystemConfigurationDto]: Nested property in path 'mtaDto.password' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'mtaDto' of bean class [com.globalsign.hb.dto.SystemConfigurationDto]: Bean property 'mtaDto' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.createApplicationContext(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:216)
    at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.loadContextLocations(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:192)
    at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.loadContext(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:172)
    at org.springframework.test.AbstractSpringContextTests.getContext(AbstractSpringContextTests.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.setUp(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:101)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.ConditionalTestCase.runBare(ConditionalTestCase.java:79)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'systemConfigurationDto' defined in file [E:\confidential\Global_Sign\40_Make\royaljelly-pc\target\test-classes\test-applicationContext-bean.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'mtaDto.password' of bean class [com.globalsign.hb.dto.SystemConfigurationDto]: Nested property in path 'mtaDto.password' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'mtaDto' of bean class [com.globalsign.hb.dto.SystemConfigurationDto]: Bean property 'mtaDto' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:409)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:297)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'mtaDto.password' of bean class [com.globalsign.hb.dto.SystemConfigurationDto]: Nested property in path 'mtaDto.password' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'mtaDto' of bean class [com.globalsign.hb.dto.SystemConfigurationDto]: Bean property 'mtaDto' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:893)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'mtaDto' of bean class [com.globalsign.hb.dto.SystemConfigurationDto]: Bean property 'mtaDto' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:890)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: How about formatting your post so that people understand it. Use the tools available.

Comment: Here is the problem: _Bean property 'mtaDto' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?_ Can you post the code for the bean that uses mtaDto?

Comment: it is SystemConfigurationDto.

Comment: thank you mael for responding to my question, sadly i am not allowed to post my SystemConfigurationDto for confidentiality reasons. The problem is mael, i am not using mtadto and it is not found in my SystemConfigurationDto but still, the error keeps on occuring.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Invalid property 'mtaDto.password' of bean class [com.globalsign.hb.dto.SystemConfigurationDto]: Nested property in path 'mtaDto.password' does not exist;
```

May be the **password** field is being accessed elsewhere like in the jsp. Its difficult to answer without the actual code. Just give a try and see if the **password** field is the cause..

Answer (score 0):

usually you get this error

```
Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException
```

when you have not defined getter and setter. Make sure  you have getter and setter  in you reference class "systemConfigurationDto".